# What is difference between history and bucketlist?

Tags: catchup

I am unable to understand the difference between history and bucketlist. 
As per documentation, bucketlist is used for:

> Efficiently transmitting a minimal "delta" of changes to the set when a peer is out of sync with the current ledger state and needs to "**catch up**".

And history is

> If the LedgerManager detects that it is out of sync with its peers, it enters "**catchup mode**", during which the history module downloads and replays historical history from a history archive to the LedgerManager, attempting to return it to synchronization with its peers.

also

> "Historical" data exists for peers to **catch up** to one another, as well as for record auditing and interoperability with other programs.

It looks like both of them are used for syncing up the nodes. however I understand that bucketlist is also used for calculating the HASH of entire set but other than that what else is the difference between two?

TIA!

Comment: Have you read through this: https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/core-data-flow.pdf? This is a good overview of data flow in Stellar-core.